# Uploadify totalBytesUploaded never clears

Tags: uploadify

According to the docs, Uploadify and totalBytesUploaded works this way:

"The total number of bytes uploaded in the current upload operation (all files)"

I just discovered that totalBytesUploaded never clears. Every time I upload some files it continues where it stopped the last time. This makes it useless when calculating percent.

Example:
Lets say that I upload 4 files, the byte count stops at 55675964 bytes when all 4 files are uploaded. Then I upload another file and the byte count continues from 55675964 up to 68502886 bytes. It gets bigger all the time for every file I upload. Is this correct or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

Just been having the same issue, solved it i think. At least so that it fits my current needs. Just wrap the uploadify-code inside a function. Call the funktion to initialize, and add a onQueueComplete with a call to the function. Thus, uploadify gets reinitialized and totalBytesUploaded gets reset.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var p = 0;
    function initUploadify() {
        $('#progress').width('0%');
        $(function() {
            $('#file_upload').uploadify({
               'swf'      : 'js/uploadify/uploadify.swf',
               'uploader' : 'js/uploadify/uploadify.php',
               'buttonText' : 'Select files',
               'width'    : 90,
               'multi'      : true,
               'queueID'  : 'q',
               'onUploadProgress' : function(file, bytesUploaded, bytesTotal, totalBytesUploaded, totalBytesTotal) {
                    p = Math.round(( totalBytesUploaded / totalBytesTotal) * 100);
                    $('#progress').width(p+'%');
               },
               'onQueueComplete' : function(queueData) {
                    initUploadify();
               }
           }
           });
        });
    }

    initUploadify();

</script>
```